# Magento 2 modules and PHP 8.2

Tags: magento2, php8.2

I'm struggling with PHP 8.2 and some Magento modules I inherited with a site.

I believe the errors are specifically because of PHP 8.2

For example:
`main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Something\Something\Helper\Index::$attributeRepository is deprecated in`

This is the line of code that it specifically references in the error

`this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;`

How do you even start to debug this? Can I add logging in to see where the error is? I believe it's down to dynamic attributes but I could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create in your `Something\Something\Helper\Index` class a property called `attributeRepository`

```
private $attributeRepository;
```

Or even better type hint it also

```
private \ClassName\Here $attributeRepository;
```

replace `\ClassName\Here` with the real class name of your attribute repository.